# Can't add variable to ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, active-model-serializers

Using Rails 5.0.0

From example code, the usage of ActiveModelSerializers is:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(resources, each_serializer: self)
```

How to add another instance_option such as `tag: true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another key, value as args to the end should work

```
 ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(resources, each_serializer: self, tag: true)
```